# socket.io-emiiter on Redis has to be reinitialized every time to send data

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

Have to re-initialize socketEmitter every-time I send data, as shown below

```
pushNotification.pushData = function (data) {
    var socketEmitter = require('socket.io-emitter')(config.redis);
    socketEmitter = socketEmitter.of('/webSocket');
    socketEmitter.in(data.orgId).emit(data.event, data.msg);

}
```

If I initialize socketEmitter globally and try to reuse it inside pushData function, the pushData function works only for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

socket.io-emitter resets the namespace after every emit. 
Fixed the issue by resetting the namespace for every data sent.